# SwaggerUI/YAML - bad indentation of a mapping entry : unable to find a reason

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

I've been stuck on a Swagger UI issue for more than an hour, searching through docs and various posts to find an explanation I cannot seem to find.

Here's part of my YAML file:

```yaml
paths:
  /projects:
    get:
      tags:
      - projects
      summary: Get projects
      description: 
      operationId: getProjects
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/Project"
      security:
      - api_key: []
```

Giving me the following :

> **Parser error** : bad indentation of a mapping entry (line 37)

Line 37 is `security:`.

The thing that bothers me is that I have other occurences of the same "code" after that, the only changing factor being the contents of `$ref`, not generating any error in the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Paths must begin with a `/`: `/projects`.
2. `description` needs a value - at least an empty string `""`.

Comment: The value for description can be empty like shown, that's valid YAML, although one might prefer to set it to `""` explicitly

Comment: @tinita: `description:` without a value evaluates to `null`. It's valid in YAML but not valid in OpenAPI/Swagger, which requires that `description` be a string.

Comment: @Helen I have a / already, I must have deleted it when pasting. Thanks for the quotes though, I it indeed what caused the issue I had. Now, more debug !

Comment: @ilomax: Glad to help! Consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247) to mark it as solution.